# MATLAB R2014b error on start

Tags: matlab

I newly installed MATLAB R2014b. It gives the following error on start:

```
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rtw\targets\shared
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rtw\targets\common\configuration\resource
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rtw\rtw\datadiff\gui
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rtw\rtw\datadiff\gui\icons
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rtw\rtw\datadiff\api
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rtw\rtw\cgv\api
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\aero\aero
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\aero\astdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\aeroblks\aeroblks
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\aeroblks\aerodemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\aeroblks\aerodemos\texture
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\comm\commobsolete
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\commblks\commblks
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\commblks\commmasks
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\commblks\commmex
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\commblks\commblksdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\commblks\commblksobsolete\v3
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\commblks\commblksobsolete\v2p5
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\commblks\commblksobsolete\v2
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\help\toolbox\commblks\examples
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\datafeed\datafeed
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\datafeed\dfgui
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\des\desblks
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\des\desmasks
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\des\desmex
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\des\desdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\distcomp\parallel\lapack
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\distcomp\worker
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\dspblks\dspblks
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\dspblks\dspmasks
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\dspblks\dspmex
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\dspblks\dspdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\dspblks\splibmex
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\help\toolbox\dspblks\examples
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rtw\targets\ecoder
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rtw\targets\ecoder\ecoderdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rtw\targets\mpt
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rtw\targets\mpt\mpt
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rtw\targets\mpt\user_specific
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\emlcoder\emlcoder
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\emlcoder\emlcodermex
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\filterdesign\filterdesign
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\filterdesign\quantization
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\filterdesign\filtdesdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\finderiv\finderiv
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\finderiv\finderivdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\finfixed\finfixed
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\finfixed\finfixdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\hdlfilter\hdlfilter
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\hdlfilter\hdlfiltdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\mpc\mpc
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\mpc\mpcdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\mpc\mpcguis
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\mpc\mpcobsolete
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\mpc\mpcutils
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\nnet\nnet\nnanalyze
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\nnet\nnet\nncustom
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\nnet\nnet\nnformat
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\nnet\nnet\nninit
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\nnet\nnguis\nftool
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\nnet\nnguis\nntool
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\nnet\nnguis\nnguiutils
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\nnet\nnguis\nntraintool
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\physmod\data_manager\data_manager
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\physmod\drive\drive
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\physmod\drive\drivedemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\physmod\elec\elec
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\physmod\elec\elecdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\physmod\foundation\foundation
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\physmod\logging\logging
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\physmod\network_engine\ne_support
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\physmod\pmir\pmir
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\physmod\simscape\m
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\physmod\simscape_language\simscape_language
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\physmod\unit_manager\unit_manager
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\qualkits\common
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\qualkits\do
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\qualkits\iec
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\slvnv\rmidemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rf\rf
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rf\rfdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rf\rftool
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rfblks\rfblks
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rfblks\rfblksmasks
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rfblks\rfblksmex
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rfblks\rfblksdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rptgen\rptgenv1
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rptgenext\rptgenext
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rptgenext\rptgenextdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rptgenext\rptgenextv1
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\sldo\sldo
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\sldo\sldodemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\sldo\sldodemos\optim
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\sldo\sldodemos\estim
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\sldo\sldodemos\estim\docexamples\adaptive
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\sldo\sldodemos\estim\docexamples\lookuptable
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\sldo\sloptim\sloptim
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\sldo\sloptim\sloptguis
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\sldo\sloptim\sloptobsolete
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\sldo\slestim\slestguis
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\sldo\slestim\slestim
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\sldo\slestim\slestmex
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\sldo\slestim\slestutil
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\slvnv\slvnv
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\slvnv\simcovdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\slvnv\do178b
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\slvnv\iec61508
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\slvnv\styleguide
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\rptgenext\slxmlcomp
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\splines
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\systemtest\systemtest
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\systemtest\systemtestdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\systemtest\viewer
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\vipblks\vipblks
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\vipblks\vipmasks
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\vipblks\vipmex
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\vipblks\vipdemos
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\vipblks\viplibmex
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\help\toolbox\vipblks\examples
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\physmod\smlink\smlink
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\physmod\smlink\smlinkdemos

Error using Settings
Undefined function or variable 'matlab.internal.getSettingsRoot'.

Error in matlabrc (line 188)
    s = Settings;
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: Do these directories exist?

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94040-why-do-i-receive-the-warning-message-warning-name-is-nonexistent-or-not-a-directory-when-i)?

Answer (score 0):

You may changed your Matlab directory files. This error or problem usually arises from displacement Matlab Toolboxes. Return files to first drive that you install Matlab files.